# Must IQueryProvider.Execute be called from within IQueryable.GetEnumerator?

Tags: linq

1) `IQueryable` essentially represents a query which when executed will yield a sequence of results.

a) I assume we execute query by either directly calling `IQueryProvider.Execute` ( immediate execution ) and passing in an expression tree  or by calling `IQueryable.GetEnumerator` ( deffered execution )?

b) is it `IQueryProvider.Execute` that actually converts the expression tree into target language ( say SQL ) and then  retrieves the results from a DB?

2)

```
public class Query<T> : IQueryable<T> ... 
{
              ... 
   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() 
   {
      return((IEnumerable<T>)this.provider.Execute(this.expression)).GetEnumerator();
   }
}

Query<string> someQuery = new Query<string>();

foreach (var item in someQuery) { ... }
```

a) In the above example query is executed by foreach calling `someQuery.GetEnumerator`. I assume that in order for the query to actually get executed, the `IQueryProvider.Execute` must be called from within  `someQuery.GetEnumerator`( via `this.provider.Execute` )?

Thank you

EDIT

1)

> If the query is returned from a Queryable method, then it is deffered
>   until GetEnumerator() or Execute() is called.

I realize that queries returned from `IQueryable` are deffered, but it seems that you're implying that queries ( those implementing `IQueryable` ) may also be returned from non-Queryable methods ( in which case they are not deffered )?

2)

> This is how LINQ-to-SQL does it. LINQ-to-Entites, however, seems to
>   bypass IqueryProvider when GetEnumerator() is called since its
>   ObjectQuery provider already has the target implementation-specific
>   command tree ready to be executed.

I've just began learning Linq to entities, but it seems that `ObjectQuery<>` represents both a query and a specific provider, while with Linq-to-sql ( don't know any Linq-to-sql, so I'm just guessing ) a query is represented with `IQueryable<>` and provider is represented with `IQueryProvider`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.a)** An `IQueryable<T>` query is usually executed by calling `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` (more often than not via a `foreach` loop). You can use `IQueryable.Execute()` as well, which will also execute the query, but you'll have to cast the result from the `IExecuteResult` object that's returned. If the query is returned from a `Queryable` method, then it is deffered until `GetEnumerator()` or `Execute()` is called.

**1.b)** Yes, `IQueryProvider.Execute` takes an implementation-specific `Expression` and converts it to the implementation-specific target form, and executes that code on the implementation backing (e.g., database or web service).

**2.a)** This is how LINQ-to-SQL does it. LINQ-to-Entites, however, seems to bypass `IQueryProvider` when `GetEnumerator()` is called since its `ObjectQuery<T>` provider already has the target implementation-specific command tree ready to be executed.

Comment: __1)__ I just meant that theoretically/technically, it's possible to implement a nonstandard query that is pre-executed. __2)__ `IQueryable<T>` and `IQueryProvider` are both LINQ-standard interfaces. `IQueryable` (which `IQueryable<T>` inherits) requires `IQueryProvider` for its `Provider` property. In fact LINQ-to-SQL's `Table<T>` implements `IQueryable` _and_ `IQueryProvider`. For Entities, a separate class, `ObjectQueryProvider` (internal), is used for `IQueryProvider`.